# Delete rows with 0 for specific columns in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, delete-row

So I want to delete rows of a matrix that contain zero, but only for specific columns. For example:

```
A = [[0 0 0 0; 1 2 0 4; 2 0 1 1; 0 0 0 0; 1 2 3 4; 0 1 2 3];
```

I want for matrix A to check if the second and/or 4th columns contain zero's. If this is true: then delete the whole row. So the result should be:

```
A = [1 2 0 4; 1 2 3 4; 0 1 2 3];
```

I used this function:

```
new_a = A(all(A,2),:)
```

But I deleted all the rows containing zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
>>> secondColIsNonzero = A(:, 2) ~= 0;
>>> fourthColIsNonzero = A(:, 4) ~= 0;
>>> keep = secondColIsNonzero & fourthColIsNonzero;
>>> newA = A(keep, :)
newA =
     1     2     0     4
     1     2     3     4
     0     1     2     3
```

to keep (i.e., not delete) columns where neither the 2nd or 4th column is zero.

For a less verbose solution, consider indexing both columns at the same time and using `all` with a dimension argument:

```
keep = all(A(:, [2 4]) ~= 0, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I have an extention on my question. For example now I want that column 2 AND column 4 are zero, I want these rows out of the matrix. So the new matrix should be: A = [1 2 0 4; 2 0 1 1; 1 2 3 4; 0 1 2 3]; Can you help me with the code? Thanks alot

Comment: Then the columns you want to keep all those where at least one of col2 or col4 is nonzero. This can be expressed as:     keep = any(A(:, [2 4]) ~= 0, 2)

Answer (score 0):

This is easily solved using the `find()` function:

```
B = A(find(A(:,2)~=0),:)
```

`find()` by default returns rows, so calling it in this case returns the index of the rows where the value on the second column is not 0.